# Youtube preloading option not available

Tags: youtube

Since I updated the Youtube app on my Nexus 5 to v5.6.31 I can no longer preload videos from my 'Watch Later' list. I have checked the settings and I can't find the option to configure this either.

Has preloading been removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, preloading [has been removed](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4629400) from version 5.6 (and above).

> To make way for some upcoming mobile features, we removed the
>   preloading feature on the YouTube app for Android. We apologize for
>   any inconvenience, and we look forward to bringing these new features
>   to you.